# How display something if check box tag is checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I’m beginner on ruby on rails and I have to build an application for my studies.
It will have users who can select differents activities and then have a list of all the things that they need for these activities ( For example if they select « Fishing » they will have a list as « bundles, fishing rod … »  ).

I have a bidirectional `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `activities` and `things`.

I would like to display all the activities and if the user selects some activities it should show `things` related to those activities.

How can I build such a view?

I try to put an « if check_box true ? »  but it doesn’t work …. If you can help me, I would be grateful !

To display my list of activities I'm using this :

```
<%= form_tag do %> <% @activities.each do |activity| %> <li> <%= check_box_tag 'activity_ids[]', activity.id %> <%= activity.name %> <%= activity.content %> </li> <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for an assignment I will just try to help you along but not give you the whole answer as your teacher wants you to learn it.

I would use the `form_for` as described in: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Then I would build the checkboxes using the `collection_check_boxes` method as shown here:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

It is unclear from your question but if the Things for each activity are already set, then you shouldn't need much more than this. If you try the methods above and have problems please edit your original question and I can try and help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it via jQuery and ajax request. Create an action in a controller which retrieve data and call that action from the ajax request and then render the response data whereever you want.